# Create monochrome CGImageRef (1-bit per pixel bitmap)

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, core-graphics, core-image

I'm trying to show a preview of an image in 1-bit monochrome, as in, not grayscale, but bitonal black and white. It's supposed to be an indication of how the image will look if it were faxed. [Formats as low as 1-bit per pixel aren't available on OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB), only 8-bit grayscale. Is there any way to achieve this effect using Core Graphics or another framework (ideally with dithering)?

I know there's a filter called CIColorMonochrome but this only converts the image to grayscale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creation of a 1 bit deep NSImageRep (and also in the CG-world) is AFAIK not supported, So we have to do it manually. It might be useful to use CIImage for this task. Here I go the classical (you may call it old-fashioned) way. Here is a code that shows how we can do it. First a gray image is created from an NSImageRep so we have a well defined and simple format whatever the source image will be formatted (could also be a PDF file). The resulting gray image is the source for the bitonal image. Here is the code for creating a gray image: (without respecting the `size / resolution` of the source image, only the pixels count!):

```
- (NSBitmapImageRep *) grayRepresentationOf:(NSImageRep *)aRep
{
    NSBitmapImageRep *newRep =
     [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
                                        pixelsWide:[aRep pixelsWide]
                                        pixelsHigh:[aRep pixelsHigh]
                                     bitsPerSample:8
                                   samplesPerPixel:1
                                          hasAlpha:NO   //must be NO !
                                          isPlanar:NO
                                    colorSpaceName:NSCalibratedWhiteColorSpace
                                       bytesPerRow:0
                                      bitsPerPixel:0 ];
    // this new imagerep has (as default) a resolution of 72 dpi

    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    NSGraphicsContext *context = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:newRep];
    if( context==nil ){
        NSLog( @"***  %s context is nil", __FUNCTION__ );
        return nil;
    }

    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:context];
    [aRep drawInRect:NSMakeRect( 0, 0, [newRep pixelsWide], [newRep pixelsHigh] )];

    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

    return [newRep autorelease];
}
```

In the next method we create an NXBitmapImageRep (bits per pixel=1, samples per pixel=1) from a given NSImageRep (one of it's subclasses) and will use the method just given:

```
- (NSBitmapImageRep *) binaryRepresentationOf:(NSImageRep *)aRep
{
    NSBitmapImageRep *grayRep = [aRep grayRepresentation];
    if( grayRep==nil ) return nil;

    NSInteger numberOfRows = [grayRep pixelsHigh];
    NSInteger numberOfCols = [grayRep pixelsWide];

    NSBitmapImageRep *newRep =
      [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
                                        pixelsWide:numberOfCols
                                        pixelsHigh:numberOfRows
                                     bitsPerSample:1
                                   samplesPerPixel:1
                                          hasAlpha:NO
                                          isPlanar:NO
                                    colorSpaceName:NSCalibratedWhiteColorSpace
                                      bitmapFormat:0 
                                       bytesPerRow:0
                                      bitsPerPixel:0 ];

    unsigned char *bitmapDataSource = [grayRep bitmapData];
    unsigned char *bitmapDataDest = [newRep bitmapData];

    // here is the place to use dithering or error diffusion (code below)

    // iterate over all pixels
    NSInteger grayBPR = [grayRep bytesPerRow];
    NSInteger binBPR = [newRep bytesPerRow];
    NSInteger pWide = [newRep pixelsWide];

    for( NSInteger row=0; row<numberOfRows; row++ ){
      unsigned char *rowDataSource = bitmapDataSource + row*grayBPR;
      unsigned char *rowDataDest = bitmapDataDest + row*binBPR;

      NSInteger destCol = 0;
      unsigned char bw = 0;
      for( NSInteger col = 0; col<pWide; ){
        unsigned char gray = rowDataSource[col];
        if( gray>127 ) {bw |= (1<<(7-col%8)); };
        col++;
        if( (col%8 == 0) || (col==pWide) ){
            rowDataDest[destCol] = bw;
            bw = 0;
            destCol++;
        }
    }
}

// save as PNG for testing and return
    [[newRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil] writeToFile:@"/tmp/bin_1.png" atomically:YES];
    return [newRep autorelease];
}
```

For error diffusion I used the following code which changes directly the bitmap of the gray image. This is allowed because the gray image itself is no longer used.

```
// change bitmapDataSource : use Error-Diffusion
for( NSInteger row=0; row<numberOfRows-1; row++ ){
    unsigned char *currentRowData = bitmapDataSource + row*grayBPR;
    unsigned char *nextRowData = currentRowData + grayBPR;
    for( NSInteger col = 1; col<numberOfCols; col++ ){
        NSInteger origValue = currentRowData[col];
        NSInteger newValue = (origValue>127) ? 255 : 0;
        NSInteger error = -(newValue - origValue);
        currentRowData[col] = newValue;

        currentRowData[col+1] = clamp(currentRowData[col+1] + (7*error/16));
        nextRowData[col-1] = clamp( nextRowData[col-1] + (3*error/16) );
        nextRowData[col] = clamp( nextRowData[col] + (5*error/16) );
        nextRowData[col+1] = clamp( nextRowData[col+1] + (error/16) );
    }
}
```

clamp is a macro defined before the method

```
#define clamp(z) ( (z>255)?255 : ((z<0)?0:z) )
```

This makes the unsigned char bytes to have valid values (0<=z<=255)